# ./manage.py Permission Denied

Tags: python, django, linux, unix, django-south

I'm trying to migrate my Django app using South and am getting permission denied warning. I'm logged in as root though (I know, risk risk, just trying to get things set-up). Why then does this get rejected?

```
root@Harold:~/OmniCloud/omnicloud: ./manage.py convert_to_south OmniCloud_App
-bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied
```

Comment: Does it have executable bit set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`manage.py` probably does not have its executable bit set, which is on purpose. Use `python manage.py` instead as per the Django docs.

Comment: Okay. The South docs say to do it this way but I'll stick to the Django way. Thanks!

Comment: `python manage.py <command>` is mentioned in docs likely just for Windows compatibility, per comments on [ticket #1040](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1040). There's nothing wrong is marking manage.py as +x

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that `./manage.py` has the executable bit set:

```
chmod a+x manage.py
```

Answer (score 2):

If for any reason you NEED to execute manage.py just run:

```
chmod +x manage.py
```

How ever, as larsmans already said, `python manage.py` is the way to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following lines at the beginning of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

(assuming that the interpreter is on the user’s PATH)
After that you can make it executable by

```
chmod +x manage.py
```

hope, it helps.